# C# Gembox Spreadsheet to populate comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, streamreader, gembox-spreadsheet

I am working on a program that uses comboboxes that are populated from a csv file, I initially just used streamreader to populate the combobox, but I was instructed to use gembox spreadsheet to populate it instead.

Here is the streamreader code that I used:

```
        private static List<ItemLine> Readfile(string fileName, string defaultValueDescription)
    {
        string path = $".\\Backend Files\\{fileName}";
        var items = new List<ItemLine>();
        int row = 0;
        //read the file
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            string lines = reader.ReadLine();
            row++;
            if (row == 1)
            {
                items.Add(new ItemLine { Description = defaultValueDescription, Quantity = 0 });
                continue;
            }
            string[] itemFields = lines.Split(",");
            ItemLine IL = new ItemLine();
            if (itemFields.Length == 2)
            {
                IL.Description = itemFields[0];
                IL.Quantity = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(itemFields[1], out int qty))
                {
                    IL.Quantity = qty;
                }
            }
            else if (itemFields.Length >= 3)
            {
                IL.Plan = itemFields[0];
                IL.Description = itemFields[1];
                IL.Quantity = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(itemFields[2], out int qty))
                {
                    IL.Quantity = qty;
                }
            }
            ///Add Items to List
            items.Add(IL);
        }
        reader.Close();
        return items;

    }
```

Here is an example of what I used gembox spreadsheet for in another part of my program which I use to update the csv files with, I think the code I am trying to figure out would look something like:

```
 public void updateFile(string filename, int range, ItemLine selectedItem, decimal outValue)
    {
        var fullPath = $".\\Backend Files\\{filename}";
        SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE -LIMITED-KEY");
        var workbook = ExcelFile.Load(fullPath, new CsvLoadOptions(CsvType.CommaDelimited));
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
        for (int i = 1; i <= range; i++)
        {
            var plan = worksheet.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
            var desc = worksheet.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
            var csvDescription = plan + " - " + desc;
            var platedescription = plan + " - ";
            if (selectedItem.ComboDescription == csvDescription)
            {
                worksheet.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = outValue;
            }
            if (selectedItem.plateDescription == platedescription)
            {
                worksheet.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = outValue;
            }
        }
        workbook.Save(fullPath, new CsvSaveOptions(CsvType.CommaDelimited));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
private static List<ItemLine> ReadFile(string fileName, string defaultValueDescription)
{
    string path = $".\\Backend Files\\{filename}";
    var workbook = ExcelFile.Load(path, new CsvLoadOptions(CsvType.CommaDelimited));
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

    var items = new List<ItemLine>();
    items.Add(new ItemLine { Description = defaultValueDescription, Quantity = 0 });

    foreach (var row in worksheet.Rows)
    {
        var cells = row.AllocatedCells;

        var il = new ItemLine();
        items.Add(il);

        if (cells.Count == 2)
        {
            il.Description = cells[0].Value.ToString();
            il.Quantity = cells[1].ValueType == CellValueType.Int ? cells[1].IntValue : 0;
        }
        else if (cells.Count >= 3)
        {
            il.Plan = cells[0].Value.ToString();
            il.Description = cells[1].Value.ToString();
            il.Quantity = cells[2].ValueType == CellValueType.Int ? cells[2].IntValue : 0;
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

Also, I'm not sure about the logic around the `defaultValueDescription`, it seems that in your `StreamReader` approach you just skip the first line in CSV because of it.

If that is the intended behavior, then add the `.Skip(1)` extension method from System.Linq, like this:

```cs
foreach (var row in worksheet.Rows.Skip(1))
{
    // ...
}
```